# Why am i getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I wrote the following python line `import scipy.io` then I went to that folder's location in the cmd:

```
C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\test>
```

and typed `pip install scipy` apparently it installed the dependencies then I went back to pycharm, ran my code and got error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'

I'm just starting off with python I'm on windows 10.

Comment: Probably you have installed it for Python 2.7.

Comment: PyCharm is most likely running from a Virtualenv Environment which means you need to download packages specifically for that environment.

Comment: I haven't actually

Comment: I think so Rob how can i do so though?

Comment: @Talar Open your project. Go to: File:Default Settings. Hit the green + button on the far right to add packages.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm has a GUI for managing which python installation you use and packages installed:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html